# Exchange 2003 - Where to set Sender name?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

Currently, people receive my mails from "`Peter Pan <peter.pan@neverland.com>`".

I would like to change the sender name, say "`Peter Pan (Neverland) <peter.pan@neverland.com>`".

I tried changing it in [Active Directory User] in the "Display Name", but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Exchange will take it's display name from AD, so you're correct so far.  There are a number of other considerations however.  Firstly you may need to wait for the recipient update service to run so that it kicks in on the GAL; this may take some time.  Secondly, users running Outlook in cached mode will need to wait until they download a fresh copy of the GAL to get this change.  Thirdly, if anyone has the old display name cached in Outlook itself, that may cause the old version to be used.  Likewise, if anyone has the old display name in a personal address book it may take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct field, Display Name but like mh mentions, there's a number of reasons why it's not coming up yet. Give it 24 hrs (default GAL download) and check it again.

When I've done those changes I usually send a test email from OWA to a Gmail, yahoo or hotmail account and you should see the change right away.

Comment: +1, good tip on the test email.